# Custom module not loading .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.7, module, theme, phtml, view

I am using Magento 1.7. The namespace is called `MasteringMagento` with a module called `example`.

My index controller is like so:

```
class MasteringMagento_Example_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    function indexAction() 
    {
        $this->loadLayout();

        return $this->renderLayout();
    }

}
```

If inside the `indexAction` I put an `echo` statement for example, it works, but it won't display a `.phtml` file.

config.xml (inside app/code/local/MasteringMagento/example/etc

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE config>

<config>

    <modules>
        <MasteringMagento_Example>
            <version>0.0.0</version>
        </MasteringMagento_Example>
    </modules>

    <global>
        <models>
            <example>
                <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Model</class>
            </example>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <example>
                <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Block</class>
            </example>
        </blocks>
        <helpers>
            <example>
                <class>MasteringMagento_Example_Helper</class>
            </example>
        </helpers>
    </global>

    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <example>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <frontName>example</frontName>
                    <module>MasteringMagento_Example</module>
                </args>
            </example>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <example>
                    <file>example.xml</file>
                </example>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>

</config>
```

example.xml (inside app/design/frontend/base/default/layout

```
<?xml version ="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE config>

<layout version="0.1.0">
    <example_index_index>
        <update handle="page_two_columns_right" />

        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" template="example/welcome.phtml">
        </reference>
    </example_index_index>
</layout>
```

And I have a folder called `example` with a `welcome.phtml` file inside located in app/design/frontend/base/default/template

What am I missing?

**EDIT:**

If I remove

```
<reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" template="example/welcome.phtml">
        </reference>
```

from `example.xml`

I get a blank content area, but if it's there I get the dog, the tags and newsletter update column, not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to close your block tag

```
<block type="core/template" template="example/welcome.phtml"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure right now but i think your block needs a unique name for it to be instantiated

`<block type="core/template" name="example.index.welcome" template="example/welcome.phtml">`

Comment: tried adding that, doesn't make a difference

Comment: hm ok yes blocks can be anonymous. thats not the problem :/ https://github.com/bragento/magento-core/blob/1.9/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php#L443